# Jupyter : [Errno -2] Name or service not known Error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, computer-vision, cloud, jupyter-notebook

Jupyter notebook was working well for me. But just after I finished installing some packages. it crashed and stopped working. I could not even find similar case on the internet.

I spent a lot of time trying to install a some special packages : cuda , imgaug, imageio, and others. I don't want to loose my work in case I tried to uninstall jupyter !

I don't know what to do here!

Should I reinstall jupyter ? Any safe cmd line to do it safely ?

I am afraid to do so because I don't want to take the risk to loose any installed packages (I spent a lot of time trying to install them)

Any help ?

PS : I am working with google cloud VM with ubuntu 16 as OS.

```
chami_soufiane_fr:~$ jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chami_soufiane_fr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 528, in get
    value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
KeyError: 'allow_remote_access'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chami_soufiane_fr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 869, in _default_allow_remote
    addr = ipaddress.ip_address(self.ip)
  File "/home/chami_soufiane_fr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/ipaddress.py", line 54, in ip_address
    address)
ValueError: '' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chami_soufiane_fr/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/chami_soufiane_fr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 266, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/home/chami_soufiane_fr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/home/chami_soufiane_fr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/chami_soufiane_fr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1629, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/home/chami_soufiane_fr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1379, in init_webapp
    self.jinja_environment_options,
  File "/home/chami_soufiane_fr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 158, in __init__
    default_url, settings_overrides, jinja_env_options)
  File "/home/chami_soufiane_fr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 251, in init_settings
    allow_remote_access=jupyter_app.allow_remote_access,
  File "/home/chami_soufiane_fr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 556, in __get__
    return self.get(obj, cls)
  File "/home/chami_soufiane_fr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 535, in get
    value = self._validate(obj, dynamic_default())
  File "/home/chami_soufiane_fr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 872, in _default_allow_remote
    for info in socket.getaddrinfo(self.ip, self.port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/home/chami_soufiane_fr/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 743, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```